# Upgrading to 14.10 from iso

Tags: upgrade, live-usb, iso

I have 14.04.1 on harddisk. Is it possible to upgrade system to 14.10 from iso file/dvd/usb?

Comment: There used to be an option of an alternate installer ISO but the idea has been [dropped since Ubuntu 12.10](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel/2012-August/035675.html). So the best option would be to do a clean install or upgrade via software updater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10 via two options, the first way is through the 'Software Updater' http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade the second method, and the one I do myself and recommend others do aswell would be a complete reinstall using a USB or CD/DVD

Download the Ubuntu 14.10 32bit or 64bit ISO and create either a USB or CD/DVD

Ubuntu 14.10 ISO http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

CD/DVD: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu

USB: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu

Remember to backup any important data with either options, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: But is it possible to add dvd as repository and upgrade from it?

Comment: I don't really understand, you can either upgrade via the Software Updater or you can boot into a CD/DVD or USB and either do a complete reinstall or as 'Takkat' said do a upgrade via the CD/DVD or USB. I personally recommend people do a complete reinstall, just remember to back anything important up.

Comment: That Computer has slow internet connection. I don't want upgrade via Software Updater. Upgrading via installing new version will erase whole system. On Ubuntu 14.10 iso there is repository. I'm adding it by apt-cdrom command. How to upgrade distribution after that?

Comment: As 'Takkat' said if you already have the Ubuntu CD/DVD you can boot into it and upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10 and it will *try (upgrades are not always successful) to keep your Home directory, software and system settings but I recommend you backup any important stuff just to be safe. If you are trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10 within Ubuntu the only way to do so as I am aware is with the Software Updater, the only other options are boot into a USB, CD, DVD and upgrade or do a fresh install

Comment: Yesterday I was upgrade from usb and I have problem with start system. Ubuntu can't decrypt encrypted LVM partitions. At night I ran the backup of my files and today I will format harddisk and install fresh system.

Comment: Good, that's why I recommend you do a backup and a complete reinstall, using encrypted volumes on Ubuntu can be tricky especially when you upgrade or reinstall. It is alot easier just to backup data, install Ubuntu, encrypt Ubuntu and copy over the backup data. Good luck with Utopic Unicorn

Answer (score 6):

From the Ubuntu installation CD/USB on choosing "Install Ubuntu" is an option to upgrade a previous release from the CD:

[image]

This option will try to keep your HOME intact, and also tries to keep installed software. Since I never tried this path I can not tell however if the result will be the same as when performing an online upgrade.

> **In any case make a backup before you start**

Comment: This is not working when you have lvm on luks and in this case system will be installed from scratch.