# update ubuntu 14.04 to 15.10 interupted and now will not boot

Tags: updates

I started to update from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 15.10 and my laptop shutdown in the middle of it. Now I it will not boot.Please help.

Comment: Would you be able to make yourself an USB-Stick with the ubuntu Instalation or a DVD so you might start the updating process via the live disk install? I'm not so firm myself but that is what i would try to get it to 15.10 so it might run again, aswell i would try the same time to backup my files in case it fails and a fresh install is the only possible option.

Answer (score 0):

Make a CD-ROM or bootable USB and upgrade from the bootable installation. I think the install process shall detect installed Ubuntu on disk and it will upgrade it. Take a look here: [Upgrading to 14.10 from iso](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543219/upgrading-to-14-10-from-iso). Only in your case it will be upgrading to 15.10.